# C# Embedded Audio Not Playing

Tags: c#, audio

I have embedded an audio file (high.wav) in the resx file for my Windows Form (by just double clicking on Form1.resx in solution explorer, Ctrl+F4, then clicking 'Add Resource'), but using

```
Stream embeddedfile = WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("high");
SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(embeddedfile);
sp.Play();
```

only plays a system sound, not the embedded one. I have tried all of the combinations of changing the Persistence from 'Linked at compile time' to 'Embedded in .resx', and Build Action from 'None' to 'Embedded Resource'. I have also tried

```
Stream embeddedfile = WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources.high;
```

which doesn't even compile, saying that 'WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'high'

Sorry is this is a dumb question, I am just starting out. If it makes any difference, I am using Windows 8.1 N.

EDIT: I guess I fixed it. Apparently you cannot add resources by going (formname).cs --> (formname).resx . You must go right click the application name, go to properties, and on the sidebar thing go to resources. I don't know what the difference is, as things added the way that works shows up in the place where it doesn't work to add it.

Answer (score 0):

For adding resource right click on the project name from project explorer then click on resources after add resource arrow ==> add Existing file from anyware
[image]

and this is code for playing this file added:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace play_Wav
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(play_Wav.Properties.Resources.myFile);
            sp.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All the code works fine and I don't know the where is the exact problem

Comment: Well this is rather odd. Upon making a new project and doing exactly as you say, it works. Upon deleting (even deleting from the resources folder in the project file) the files and re-adding them in the same way I did with the new one, it still doesn't work. This is really confusing.